# 500 error depending on data submitted in POST request

Tags: node.js, azure

**Setup:** NodeJS / Express / Helmet API running on Azure App Service, CORS set to allow * so should be all fine.
Client web setup running locally on NodeJS (http://localhost:3000)

I'm trying to POST some JSON from the web client to the API for login validating purposes. Works for some requests and not others, seemingly depending on what actual values I am posting.

I've got a bit of code that uses the Fetch API to send login details and validate them, as follows:

```
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/auth/validate`, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({EmailAddress: email, Password: password}),
    }).catch(error => {
        alert('Unable to check login');
    });
```

If the value of **email** and **password** are both just me leaning on the keyboard, say 'skdjflsjdf' then it's all fine - the server gets my POST, validates that the login is rubbish and bounces back my error. It allows it because I get the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** * header back, so Chrome is happy.
If the value of email is an actual email address, I don't get the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin:** * header back and Chrome gets very upset of course. 
I can't even begin to imagine how I've gone wrong here and I certainly don't seem to be able to find the right phrase to Google for a sensible answer. I'd really appreciate any help... Thanks.

Comment: In the case where you don’t get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error instead of a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Yes, it's 500 along with the Chrome red text warning about request being blocked by CORS policy because of lack of the above header

Comment: So yeah, you have a 500 problem to fix, not a CORS problem. The only reason you see the message about CORS is that 500 errors are never going to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. You probably want to look through the server logs on the server side to see what messages the server is logging about the internal failure that causes it to end up responding with that 500 error.